# Why is my kNN Search not returning matches when the submitted image is slightly different?

Tags: database, elasticsearch, computer-vision, knn

I have an Elastic Search Index which is setup to store dense_vectors.

The dense vectors field is configured like so.

```
image_dense_vector: {
  type: 'dense_vector',
  dims: 512,
  index: true,
  similarity: 'dot_product'
}
```

I have a process setup which utilizes the python `img2vec` library along with the Resnet18 model to generate a Vector with 512 dimensions like so.

```
img2vec = Img2Vec(cuda=False, model="resnet18", layer_output_size=512)

resized_image = img.resize((224, 224))
vector = img2vec.get_vec(resized_image, tensor=False)
vector = helpers.normalize_vector(vector)

es.index(index=request.index, id=id,
   body={"image_dense_vector": vector},
)
```

To search for results I'm passing in an image and getting the vector for that image the same way as above then passing it into a ES query like so.

```
{
  "field": "image_dense_vector",
  "query_vector": vector,
  "k": limit,
  "num_candidates": 50,
}
```

The problem I'm running into is that if my query image has a smudge or isn't perfectly cropped the result images are off. The total number of images indexed is about 500,000.

**I would like to be able to figure out a way to make it so that the images don't need to be a perfect match to get a accurate response.**

Here are some example images and the original image that was index.

Example Query Images:
[image]
[image]

Indexed Image:

[image]